# GDB script too slow, need help/suggestions

Tags: gdb, core-file

I am writing a gdb script to analyse a core file. The purpose of whom is as follows:
1] I am looking for packets which are scattered in the 64Mb space. The packet has a magic number of 4 bytes. Hence I have to read 4 bytes at a time.
2] I have to read a total of 64Mb of data starting from a given address.
3] Once i find the packet I should print the deatils of the packet and continue looking for other packets.
4] Hence in my script the main loop runs for 64*1024*1024/4 =16777216 times in the worse case.
Whats the problem:
The script is taking about 3 hours or more which is totally impractical.
I am assuming this is because its a interpreted language, also the number of loops is pretty large.
Any suggestions/improvements are welcome. Kindly help me here.

Answer (score 2):

If you think the problem is with gdb being slow you could dump the memory area you are interested in with "dump binary memory" then use a small program written in whatever you think will be faster to analyse the dump.

Comment: I tried this, but in my case if I dump the memory, I wont be having the access to the packet structures. :(

Comment: But it was a good idea, I did not know about memory dump. It will help to solve my other problems.

Answer (score 2):

the find command should do everything you want,
without having to loop every 4 bytes or so,
it stores the address of the last found packet in $_
(untested, but should be something to the effect of)

```
(gdb) python x = list()
(gdb) set $start_addr = 0x....
(gdb) set $last_end = $start_addr
(gdb) set $_ = $start_addr+1
(gdb) while $_ != $last_end
 >find $last_end, $start_addr + 64*1024*1024, 0x42
 >set $last_end = $_
 >python x.append(gdb.parse_and_eval("$_"))
 >end
(gdb) python print map(lambda(y): str(y), x)
```

if you don't have python you can use set logging overwrite off,set logging on,print,set logging off